# Python script to convert RBG image dataset into Grayscale images using pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, rgb, file-handling, grayscale

I want to `convert an image RGB dataset to Grayscale dataset using pillow`. I want to write a script that takes in the dataset path and converts all images one by one into grayscale. At the end I want to save this script, and want to run this script on the server to avoid the copying of huge data to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this code would work for you?

Code:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
dir = '/content/pizza_steak/test/pizza'
for i in range(len(os.listdir(dir))):
    # directory where images are stored
    dir = '/content/pizza_steak/test/steak'

    # get the file name
    file_name = os.listdir(dir)[i]

    # creating a final path
    final_path = dir + '/' + file_name

    # convet and save the image
    Image.open(final_path).convert('L').save(f"/content/meow/gray{file_name}")

    # uncomment this is you want to delete the file
    # os.remove(final_path)
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I want to save it to some folder instead of .show()

Comment: then instead of showing use `gray_image.save('img-name.png')`

Comment: Yes, thank you. How do I convert multiple images and not only one image?

Comment: well, there are so many options to choose from as per my knowledge I would say loop through `os.listdir('dir path')` and convert one by one and after converting the image you can delete the original and yeah instead of png use .jpg to save some space.

Comment: Could you please let me know how do I proceed with a folder of RGB that is to be converted to grayscale, I need a folder created with all converted images at the end.
Now, I know the logic, but cannot write the actual lines in python. ( as i have a different background) thank you in advance.

Comment: @aarya I have edited my answer please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246061/discussion-between-ameya-and-aarya).